# Cannot set ctrl+left/right in Tmux to move by whole words

Tags: 18.04, tmux

I have used this command: `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` in the `.tmux.conf` file from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/360832/how-can-i-make-ctrlleft-right-keys-to-move-by-whole-word-in-tmux) to move by whole words in tmux but it's not working. I have been googling this issue for the last 3 hours and none of the solutions work.

I am running:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Tmux: 2.6
- GNOME Shell 3.28.3

[My tmux config file.](https://pastebin.com/Up7QkwNA)

Comment: I think the `bind-key -n "C-Left" ...` you have will take precedence. You should try removing it, and probably then not need xterm-keys.

Comment: @meuh Sometimes even I am amazed at my stupidity. Thanks for pointing the error.